# mysql update field without to select first

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to update a field but previously entered contents should be kept. Is there a way to this with one query without to select first the content.

example I have a field by name **protocol** what is having entries exmpl.

1. > this is a prevoius entry

than on update should look like

1. > this is a prevoius entry
2. > this is a newer entry

instead of this a better workaround

```
SELECT protocol FROM my_table WHERE id = 1
 than I should add the new entry to my field and make the update

UPDATE my_table
SET protocol=new value
WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to [concatenate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the existing and the new string. The function is called [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) in MySQL:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET protocol = CONCAT(protocol, "\n", "new entry");
```